# Building a dll with Go 1.7

Tags: windows, go, dll, mingw-w64

Is there a way to build a dll against Go v1.7 under Windows ?

I tried a classic

```
go build -buildmode=shared main.go
```

but get

> -buildmode=shared not supported on windows/amd64

**update**
Ok, I've got my answer. For those who are interested :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/ckFZAZbnjzU

Comment: `-buildmode=shared` is a Go shared library, which wouldn't make a DLL anyways. You most likely were looking for `buildmode=c-shared`, though that hasn't been worked on for windows yet, and you can follow [issue #11058](https://golang.org/issue/11058)

Comment: Btw, Go 1.10 does support building windows DLLs since update in Oct 10, 2017.

`go build -buildmode=c-shared`

That single command will generate any DLL for Windows systems.

refer to:

https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/69091

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As of Go 1.10, -buildmode=c-shared is now supported on Windows.

Release notes:
https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#compiler

So now compiling to DLL is a one-liner:

```
go build -o helloworld.dll -buildmode=c-shared
```

I believe the headers are only compatible with GCC.  If you're only exposing C-types, this should not be a big issue.  I was able to get LoadLibrary to work in Visual Studio without the header.

Comment: I get `go: no Go source files` when adding a target OS via `GOOS=windows`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my answer.

Comment: Hi. When I load .dll in C++ I get the following error : `fatal error: out of memory allocating heap arena metadata`. Would you mind looking at my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72097599/how-to-use-golangs-c-shared-dll-in-c

Answer (score 22):

```
go build -buildmode=c-archive github.com/user/ExportHello
```

====> will build  `ExportHello.a`, `ExportHello.h`

Take the functions built in `ExportHello.a` and re-export in `Hello2.c`

```
gcc -shared -pthread -o Hello2.dll Hello2.c ExportHello.a -lWinMM -lntdll -lWS2_32
```

====> will generate `Hello2.dll`

Answer (score 13):

There is a project on github which shows how to create a DLL, based on, and thanks to user7155193's answer.

Basically you use GCC to build the DLL from golang generated .a and .h files.

First you make a simple Go file that exports a function (or more).

```
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export PrintBye
func PrintBye() {
    fmt.Println("From DLL: Bye!")
}

func main() {
    // Need a main function to make CGO compile package as C shared library
}
```

Compile it with:

```
go build -buildmode=c-archive exportgo.go
```

Then you make a C program (goDLL.c) which will link in the .h and .a files generated above

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "exportgo.h"

// force gcc to link in go runtime (may be a better solution than this)
void dummy() {
    PrintBye();
}

int main() {

}
```

Compile/link the DLL with GCC:

```
gcc -shared -pthread -o goDLL.dll goDLL.c exportgo.a -lWinMM -lntdll -lWS2_32
```

The goDLL.dll then can be loaded into another C program, a freepascal/lazarus program, or your program of choice.

The complete code with a lazarus/fpc project that loads the DLL is here:
https://github.com/z505/goDLL

Comment: These questions are out of scope but please humor me: why do we need (the entire) gcc, and whats the easiest way to get gcc (or presumably just the linker portion?) & get it on path properly? Finally, would llvm tooling (llgo) make this easier?

Answer (score 1):

Just tested on Windows 10 and this works perfectly:

```
> go version                                                                                     
go version go1.17.2 windows/amd64

> cat main.go
package main

import (
  "C"
)

//export Entry
func Entry(){
  main()
}

func main() {
  // do something
}

> go build -buildmode=c-shared -o mydll.dll main.go
> dumpbin /EXPORTS mydll.dll 
File Type: DLL
..
    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 ...      Entry

> rundll32.exe .\mydll.dll,Entry
```