# Go to library to C# | BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, go, compilation, shared-libraries, shared

I would like to create a library out of go-code and use it inside a C# winforms project.
**For the error scroll to the bottom.**

**Setup**

- GO 1.10.2
- tdm-gcc-5.1.0-3
- Windows 10 / x64
- Go-project called `exprt`

**What I've tried**

I've created a minimal go-tool that creates a file in the working-dir:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "C"
)

func main() {
    // nothing here
}

//export Test
func Test() {
    os.OpenFile("created_file.txt", os.O_RDONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666);
}
```

*The next steps were taken from [Building a dll with Go 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573401/building-a-dll-with-go-1-7).*

I've then compiled to `c-archive` with the following command: `go build -buildmode=c-archive` which gives me `exprt.a` and `exprt.h`.

After that I've created a file called `goDLL.c` (1:1 as in the link above) and inserted this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "exprt.h"
// force gcc to link in go runtime (may be a better solution than this)
void dummy() {
    Test();
}
int main() {
}
```

Lastly I've run this command to create my final dll:
`gcc -shared -pthread -o goDLL.dll goDLL.c exprt.a -lWinMM -lntdll -lWS2_32`
which gave me "goDLL.dll".

**My problem**

In C# I've created a winforms-project with 1 button that calls this declared function (copied the dll to the debug-folder):

```
[DllImport("goDLL.dll")]
private static extern void Test();
```

**Error**

`System.BadImageFormatException: "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"`

Sorry for that big block of text but this was the most minimal test I could think off.

I appreciate every help in here.

Comment: why is the name of the referenced external function `File` and not `Test`? the error you get is related to 32bit WOW vs. 64bit image, probably due to the `-lWS2_32` compiler flag. both must have the same bitness.

Comment: @dlatikay Was just a typo. In my first test both was called `File()`. Edited the question.

Comment: I just don't get whats the counterpart of `WS2_32` for 64bit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the given answer here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ee3df896-1d33-451b-a8a3-716294b44b2b/socket-programming-on-64bit-machine?forum=vclanguage there is written:

> The implementation is in a file called ws2_32.dll and there are 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the DLL in 64-bit Windows.

So the build as described in my question is correct.

**Solution**
The C#-Project has to be explicitly set to x64. `AnyCPU` won't work and throw the error shown in the question above.

Everything is working now. I'm leaving the question and answer as this is a full explanation of how to get go-code running out of C#.