# Cross compiling from Windows to other OSs

Tags: go

I read [this](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/03/03/cross-compilation-just-got-a-whole-lot-better-in-go-1-5) and [this](https://gist.github.com/asukakenji/f15ba7e588ac42795f421b48b8aede63) about this activity, and the action mentioned as:

```sh
% env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=386 go build hello.go

// or

% env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build hello.go

// and so on
```

But in Windows there is no command named `env`, I got the below:

```sh
'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check supported compilation tools: `go tool dist list`
Cross compiling not working with `cgo`, i.e. not working with any file has `import "C"`

At Powershell

```
# For ARM
$env:GOOS = "linux" 
$env:GOARCH = "arm" 
$env:GOARM = "7" 
go build -o main main.go
# For darwin
$env:GOOS = "darwin" 
$env:GOARCH = "amd64" 
go build -o main.dmg main.go
# same for others
$env:GOOS = "windows" 
$env:GOARCH = "amd64" 
go build -o main.exe main.go
```

At CMD `Command Prompt`:

```sh
set GOOS=darwin
set GOARCH=amd64
go build -o main.dmg main.go
```

To do it in Linux or Mac and compiling to Win

```sh
GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main.exe main.go
```

Cross compiling will silently rebuild most of standard library, and for this reason will be quite slow. To speed-up the process, you can install all the standard packages required for cross compiling on your system, for example to install at Linux/Mac the cross compiling requirements for `windows-amd64` use:

```sh
GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go install
```

Similar for any other OS you need to cross compile for it at Windows

Answer (score 1):

On windows powershell you should be able to do:

```
$env:GOOS = "linux"
$env:GOARCH = "arm"
$env:GOARM = "7"
go build hello.go
```

Comment: Thanks, i did the below:`$env:GOOS = "darwin" $env:GOARCH = "amd64" go build grouping.go` and got a new file EITHOUT extension

Comment: add `-o grouping.exe`

Comment: mm `.exe` is not this only for Windows ?

Comment: you can put whatever extension you want, I was just showing an example

Comment: I wrote `go build grouping.go -o test.dmg` and got `can't load package: named files must be .go files: -o`

Comment: oh sorry, when you do `-o` the order matters for some reason, you have to do `go build -o test.dmg grouping.go`

Comment: Deeply appreciated, do you have an idea how to make `.dll` dynamic library?

Comment: not sure, never done it, maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573401/building-a-dll-with-go-1-7

Comment: How to do it from `Mac` and compile to `Windows` I tried the below: `hasan@Hasans-MacBook-Air mod % $env:GOOS = "windows"
zsh: command not found: :GOOS
hasan@Hasans-MacBook-Air mod % env GOOS = "windows"
env: GOOS: No such file or directory`